# IOS UILabel doesn't update until i reload the app or clicking elsewhere

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I'm new to iOS development and I'm new to the concept of closures. Using storyboard I created a `UIButton` and `UILabel`  so when I click the button it shows an alert with an action and when i dismiss the alert the label increment the number inside the label but I want that increment to be after the alert dismiss so I used the concept of closure so I can delay the incrementation of the nummber inside the label like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLbl: UILabel!
    var count = 1

    func updateLabels(){
        numberLbl.text = String(count)
        count += 1
    }

    @IBAction func btnPressed(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "hello", message: "this is an alert", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
            print("incrementing.... ") // it print this text
                                       // in console
            self.updateLabels()        // but not this line does not work
        // but when i reload the app it updates the number label
        /// !!!!!!!!
        })

        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

But what happen is that when ever i run the simulator and click the button the alert shows up and click the action to dismiss it but the label does not increment until i touch some side button on the simulator or i reload the app after that it increments

i tried that on a physical device and i works fine but on simulator it does not

i'm using a macbook pro late 2011

thanks

Comment: Judging from your comments below, I think your computer is too old and slow.

Comment: hey, after a long search i found out that it's because of a bug in macs with intel HD graphic 3000 so it's a driver bug and the workaround for that is to execute this command which did work for me (thankfully) :
' defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 2 ' or use 1 depending on your hardware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a long search i found out that it's because of a bug in macs with intel HD graphic 3000 so it's a driver bug and the workaround for that is to execute this command which did work for me (thankfully)

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferEmulationHint 2
```

or use 1 depending on your hardware

thank you guy for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You updated the UILabel text before updating the count variable

```
var count : Int = 1 {
    didSet {
        numberLbl.text = "\(count)"
    }
}

func updateLabels() {    
    count += 1
}
```

Comment: I would even get rid of the `updateLabels` function and just increment the value directly.

Comment: Just in case of changing count variable in whole controller not only this function

Comment: hi there :), when i created the numberlabel (UILabel) so it already has 0 and initialized the count with 1 and before the count increments it will update UILabel By 1 and then count increments for the next call but the problem is that the UI hangs and i have to touch volume side button and the UILabel increments suddenly

Answer (score -1):

Only aspect of your code that I changed in your code was the way you have your button declared.

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: UIButton)
```

Beyond that, you might want to try a clean (Command Shift K) and try rebuilding.

Outside of that, I ran your code as-is and it worked correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah i totally forgot about the argument "(_ sneder: UIButton)".
 but my issue is that the label does't update ( increment the number) automatically after i dismiss the alert but it increments after i touch side volume button like it's hanging there waiting for something ??? that's weird

Comment: Honestly that sounds like a simulator bug.  Have you tried testing on a device?

Comment: well yes after several failed attempts using the simulator i did test it on a physical device and it works just fine but on the simulator it has a weird behaviour where i have to touch the side volume button to force the label to update or the whole UIView in general and it shows the proper number !